# Serial downvotes for single tag

Tags: discussion, questions

After posting a question tagged under [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3), I was looking at other questions with the same tag and noticed that a majority of new questions get downvotes within a few hours of them being posted.

A lot of the ones that are at a score of 0 have a +1/-1 voting score ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711508/change-google-maps-api-route-planner-language), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36700943/map-markers-are-disappearing-after-a-certain-amount-of-toggle-clicks), [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694269/display-google-map-with-correctly-positioned-marker-using-a-google-maps-url)). Is there someone specifically targeting these tags? Does the daily serial voting bot check these patterns?

**tl;dr**: is there anything stopping me from downvoting all of the questions in a certain tag that I don't like?

Comment: The ones I just looked at probably deserve it. Probably just correlation, not causation: https://xkcd.com/552/

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara How so? A majority of them could use edits for formatting & clarity, but the content of the questions are still relevant.

Comment: The ones you've listed here aren't too bad, but there were a bunch of low-quality downvoted questions I saw on the latest tab (not as bad as say, the [tag:dreamweaver] tag though).

Comment: The [tag:dreamweaver] tag is fairly understandable. The worst questions tagged under dreamweaver tend to have multiple downvotes and are sparsely downvoted, whereas most questions on [tag:google-maps-api-3] have only a single downvote.

Comment: Just stumbled here: I'm surprised about the many downvotes, may I ask what people sees in this question that makes it deserve downvoting (as opposed to simply not answering or a reply explaining why the OP is incorrect?). Is there something going on that I don't see?

Comment: @KevinEvans What does this have to do with _serial voting_ actually? May be you're using the wrong term for what you're trying to describe.

Comment: @jjmontes Individual questions with one or two votes either way does not indicate serial voting to me. It looks like a lot of the question in that tag are also tagged with [javascript], which is a more populated tag, which means more traffic and thus more scrutiny/votes overall. Nothing here looks particularly malicious or even out of the ordinary.

Comment: @jjmontes - Down votes on meta are often used to express disagreement. This isn't a feature request but it could be that people disagree that the tag in the question is being targeted or disagree with calling it serial down voting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it appears to be serial (serial, as in a predictable pattern) voting. Roughly 80-90% of the questions get a downvote within an hour if they get tagged under that. Other tags, including more populous tags, don't have a rate that high.

Comment: @KevinEvans Well, as mentioned it's a standing term here, and means something different as you're describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **tl;dr:** is there anything stopping me from downvoting all of the questions in a certain tag that I don't like?

No, there's nothing really wrong about that (technically), and the [serial voting reversal mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) won't get after this.

The term *"serial voting"* usually is meant to describe voting anomalies targeting a specific user, not targeting tags.

But it's a silly action to downvote maybe, because it might not really refer to the questions quality, that the OP has mistakenly chosen a poor tag that exists in the system.

---

Though the better action about tags you don't like or believe these aren't useful, is to propose an edit removing that tag.

As from your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321332/serial-downvotes-for-single-tag?noredirect=1#comment334788_321332):

> Roughly 80-90% of the questions get a downvote within an hour if they get tagged under that. Other tags, including more populous tags, don't have a rate that high. .

This seems to improve that that particular tag isn't useful to put questions in a better context.

May be you could additionally come up with a [tag burination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) request on meta to support your campaign.

---

**Well, let's get serious:**

The [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) is a pretty frequent tag (18,389 questions currently), and it's unlikely that this tag gets burinated soon.

Though there seems to be some coincidence that this tag comes along with low question quality as observed from the downvotes. That might happen systematically.

Comment: "No, there's nothing really wrong about that (technically)" - Logically there is something wrong with serial downvoting in a tag. Only questions that are bad should be downvoted. It's unlikely that all questions in a tag are bad, so users downvoting all (many) questions in a tag are doing something wrong, I guess.

Comment: @Trilarion Didn't I say that: _"But it's a silly action ..."_??