# Why do I get a down vote on every VHDL question I ask?

Tags: support, questions, downvotes

I'm an experienced VHDL designer, but sometimes I have questions, too.

Many of my questions in the topic of VHDL receive a -1 downvote right after posting them on SO. There was never a comment stating any dislike, off-topic notice, silliness, or what ever. I suspect that I get these downvotes in the review process, because it's mostly within several minutes after asking the question. As I have enough reputation to see close votes, there is no pending close vote for my question.

Here is my [newest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016020/vsim-does-not-accept-modelsimini-parameter-on-windows), which received a downvote.

Yes, in this case I found the answer by myself, but this questions documents a strange behavior/bug in a commonly used software.

How to deal with it? Is it always the same user voting me down?

Comment: Isn't it better to ask about VHDL at electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: It looks like it's not just you. About 40% of the most recent [vhdl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) questions have at least one downvote. That seems like more than normal. Is there perhaps a group roaming around that considers VHDL questions off-topic for some reason?

Comment: If they're code related questions, they shouldn't be considered off-topic. (But you might get better answers on a more specialized site, so consider that too.)

Comment: Yes, VHDL questions are split across SO and EE. We more advanced users (rep > 1000) decide where to ask and advise others to move there question if it's more algorithm / programing related or more hardware / electrical related to the appropriate site.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Can you track it a person or group? Can you correlate it to 0..30 minutes after asking? Maybe you should check Verilog, too. I noticed that new users get down votes even for good and detailed questions, too.

Comment: Note that if you think you are being targeted by a single user, you can also raise a moderator flag explaining the whole situation. If it's too long to describe in a flag (as it seems to be in this case) then coming to Meta is the right solution.

Comment: It seems like someone's subscribed to the tag and votes down on anything that comes up. Probably something for an SE developer to look into.

Comment: It appears that VHDL, Verilog programming issue can be related to specific hardware, settings etc and there is a fair chance that EE might have experts that can answer from experience. Comparing this with SO it is also possible that some hardware based questions in EE can be simply programming flags or issues that should be posted on SO. This can create duplicate questions and if there is a way to link them on both sites using flags then that should be used (in future maybe). The downvote on SO should not be for this reason alone and benefit of doubt should go to OP.

Comment: It would be nice if we could vote to migrate questions between SO and EE. Currently it's not possible. Other site combinations (e.g. SO -> Tex) can do so.

Comment: @Paebbels Yes, I have asked for this too. I believe EE can migrate questions here, but not the other way around. The EE site is a rather frequent candidate for things that needs migration.

Comment: @Paebbels in the most recent question you referenced you didn't actually ask a question (it reads more as a statement that some error hapens) which is possibly why you've been downvoted

Comment: Issues like this are why the request to make downvotes non-anonymous come up.

Comment: Don't fret - I have had the same experience posting where questions get downvoted within a few minutes of my posting (almost always just by 1) with no additional comments.  It used to frustrate me, but now I just don't care.  There are clearly users who downvote for the sake of chaos rather than constructive feedback.

Comment: So, the question you linked did lack an [MCVE].  In order to answer it, someone would have to first generate an [MCVE] or recognize the error message from having the exact same problem happen to them before and remember the solution, or be you.  So it wasn't a great SO question.

Comment: @Yakk It is a MCVE. because the error is already caused by passing the `-modelsimini` parameter to `vsim`. There is no VHDL code file needed to cause this behavior.

Comment: In addition to users who vote for the sake of chaos there are also some who like to take their personal frustrations on other users; I guess it's hard to resist the remoteness. Recently a downvote on many of my posts, very unrelated to each other and on very unrelated SEs, suddenly appeared at the same time and it's obvious that the author is someone whose point I had openly (but civilly) criticized just shortly before and who seemed a bit annoyed by that. As long as it's just one it's no big deal as if it were more SO's mechanisms would automatically fix that.

Comment: @BilltheLizard but downvoting (especially without a comment) is not the correct thing to do when something is considered off-topic… they should raise flags or possibly talk to the poster first. (Aside from the question of whether it actually *is* off-topic; I’m with Laurel on that most things can fit SO even if they also fit other sites; actually, I’d guess that EE is more focused on the hardware side of things?)

Comment: I'm not seeing an actual question in your question; it just reads like a bug report.

Comment: That question doesn't appear to be about programming, instead it's relating to configuring some tool that i'm not familiar with. (maybe the tool is used for programming? i dunno)

Comment: Let's say that I have identified one person who is pretty heavily downvoting posts in this tag. They're not targeting any one person, so our normal standards of handling serial downvoting don't apply. When one person is targeting another in revenge, that's pretty easy to make a call on, but not here. If I confront them about this, they will state that they're free to vote based on how they judge the quality of the content. The question is: how do I distinguish between votes that someone leaves based on their own strict quality standard and them abusing the voting system?

Comment: @SomethingDark exactly - the people who downvoted should have commented with the pretty standard "what are you asking?"

Comment: @BradLarson - To me the defining line would be, what percent of this user's questions in the [VHDL] tag has the theoretical user downvoted. 10%? No big deal. 20%? Same. 50%? Kind of shady. 75%+? I mean, at what point does it not become personal. Clearly at 75%+ the voting is targeted. In this case, of 36 questions that would be 27. So, in theory, if said user had downvoted at least 27 of those posts there is no doubt in my mind that there is a problem. If it is 18, then I am on the fence but still quizzical. If it is less than 18 I would not make assumptions.

Comment: @BradLarson - Not one to skip the available tools at my disposable, I manually counted the posts this user has with downvotes in that tag. 11. Out of 36. At this point I am not sold at all that this is an issue considering the range of the posts is several years and the theoretical user is not targeting this one person but as you indicate the whole tag. However, is 30% considered crossing the line as far as targeting a single user? Was it even 30%? That would mean that every downvote was from the hypothetical user.

Comment: I think the user or group isn't targetting me personally. I think the whole tag is a target. I was a bit frustrated when I wrote this title, because it's very unlikely to get a -1 within several minutes. So consider my user account an example for many other VHDL tag users :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I feel like I got the same treatment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33295644/2615940). I know it's a pretty basic question, but I thought I met SO guidelines when I asked it, and still got a random downvote.

Comment: @TravisJ I see 90% crap with absolutely no research effort in a tag I'm following. Most of them are already answered numerous times and many don't even have a proper problem description or code required reproduced the issue. I do downvote them. I do upvote the 10% good questions and wish they were the majority. I'm not targeting anyone. I don't think you can draw such a line on this matter.

Comment: Someone with a habit of checking `VHDL` question regularly has a cat with a habit of running over the keyboard to get his attention. That's all there's to it folks...

Comment: It's self-answered. Some people hate self-answered questions. I know that from experience.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, but the downvote was before the self-answer....

Comment: @Paebbels: Never mind then :)

Comment: I don't know anything about vhdl but [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016020/vsim-does-not-accept-modelsimini-parameter-on-windows#comment61587832_37016020) makes me immediately downvote your Q+A. It might very well just be a poor question in the first place.

Comment: Wow. The "meta effect" seems to include getting downvotes for 3 month old questions ...

Comment: The meta effect does not discriminate based on question age ;)

Comment: So you started off with one down-vote...would have been better just letting [*sleeping dogs lie*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/let_sleeping_dogs_lie).

Comment: @Lankymart A -1 doesn't hurd my reputation, but it looks strange if a >3k user has a negative ranked question .... This gives an impression that he's not able to formulate a question. I think it's a greater deal for new users. Getting frustrated and leaving SO. Maybe it's a cause why the VHDL tag is unpopular or having no refined questions.

Comment: Similar case happens to my questions as well. I don't understand why. Here is one of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37040448/how-to-write-docblock-comment-for-a-function-having-no-param-and-return-values-i. I would like to know why it happens too. Thanks for posting this question @Paebbels

Comment: Highly related: [Spam Voting - Should we stop it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269082/spam-voting-should-we-stop-it)

Comment: @Zizouz212 How is this related?

Comment: @Paebbels Circumstances are similar - voting appears to be based on nothing, since there's a down vote on every question, and it doesn't seem to be based on scope or quality.

Answer (score 40):

There *are* some tags that should immediately be down voted (for being off-topic), such as [project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management), but [vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vhdl) isn't one of them.

If your question has code, it doesn't matter what the code *does*, as long as it meets the quality standards of SO (grammar, MVCE, length, etc).

Some of the questions posted under that tag *do* deserve down votes because they don't meet the quality guidelines for the site. This is true for any other topic, too.

I checked what's on and off topic for [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

On topic:

> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

They do list "Programming software for a PC" as being off topic, but I think that VHDL never falls into that category because it's only used for hardware. If it's on topic there too, you have a choice of where to post it. Personally, I think that you would get better results on a smaller, dedicated site.

This, however, doesn't explain the down votes on what seem to be well written posts (as far as I can tell not knowing the subject). In fact, the post you linked seems to be the only one not negative (which is probably the meta effect more than anything else).

The tag is fairly small, with ~3,000 questions, so it's even more suspicious this would happen. Most of the recent posts have less than 40 views, and I'm sure that many of those are the meta effect.

The system currently doesn't detect serial down voting on tags, so there's not much we can do without a mod. We might even need a super mod (ie, a developer). But there are some things that we can look at to make a hypothesis:

- It takes **125 reputation** to down vote, so it has to be one or more people who have at least spent some time on the site.
- It's possible that they don't have the ability to close vote yet, which would mean that they're **< 3k rep**.
- We're **not seeing any vandalism**, which is good (but it might have provided more information if we were).
- The down votes are **VERY** evenly distributed. This is an important detail, because it's very unlikely that it's a link from Reddit or something (otherwise we would see multiple down votes on posts).

I'm steering towards the idea of a **single vigilante**, because it's very unlikely that multiple people would be able to coordinate like that.

If I'm right, (and they haven't set up a program to do this), then the down votes should all be within a time frame, which will could tell us which area on Earth the down votes come from (this also assumes that they sleep at whenever night is in their timezone).

---

Brad Larson's [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322363/why-do-i-get-a-down-vote-on-every-vhdl-question-i-ask/322427#comment340865_322363):

> Let's say that I have identified one person who is pretty heavily downvoting posts in this tag. They're not targeting any one person, so our normal standards of handling serial downvoting don't apply... If I confront them about this, they will state that they're free to vote based on how they judge the quality of the content. The question is: how do I distinguish between votes that someone leaves based on their own strict quality standard and them abusing the voting system?

I think the best option would be to tell the user(s) that we are discussing this here on Meta. They have a right to remain anonymous (as much as we might not like it), but they should at least know that we're discussing this here. If they want to reveal themselves, then so be it.

---

I think the other thing we need to think about is the other type of serial voting: serial up voting. Would we be as concerned if somebody was serial up voting a tag? Maybe not...

Comment: Regarding your update, that comment reads to me as a "Alright, so what if we do an investigation and do find this to be the case? What can we even do about it?" rather than a "Oh, yeah, I know who's doing this so what should I do now?"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - The ambiguity is intentional. The real question is: if we do find someone downvoting a lot of questions within a single tag, is that their right? If not, where do we draw the line between someone's idea of quality control and abuse of the voting system? If they're not targeting one person, what can moderators do? Tell them not to downvote so much? Invalidate all of their votes to everyone?

Comment: @Brad: Ok, if this person exists, and is who I suspect it is, then they're just very keen on MVCE. They also have some understanding of the language, which is unusual on the HDL tags. MVCE downvoting is their right, but perhaps it doesn't work on this tag, which needs to be more conversational than C++, for example.  What might help is clarification that not all questions need to be MVCE.

Comment: @BradLarson What's wrong with downvoting lots of posts in a tag? If I am an expert in Crystal Reports, I will mostly look at questions in the Crystal Reports tag. If there are 10 new questions and 9 of them are bad, is it serial downvoting to downvote those 9 questions?

Comment: @EML Can you elaborate a bit? Can most VHDL questions be answered without an MVCE? I'm not sure what you mean by "controversial", either.

Comment: @Aaroninus: No, but let's say you downvoted that 1 good question too, because the 9 bad questions have conditioned you to think that nothing good ever comes out of [crystal-reports]. That's where Brad's dilemma really comes in IMO (and is also the main issue the OP is trying to address).

Comment: @Laurel: 'conversation-al'... :) Given that most contributors are either beginners or are not naturally 'programmers', most issues involve clarification of basic concepts, rather than pointing out errors in MVCEs. Another issue is that a class of tools (synthesisers, which generate circuits from the 'program') essentially work on heuristics, rather than implementing the LRM, and these heuristics can be vendor-dependent. That's why the comp.lang threaded conversation format works so well, and the SO question/answer format doesn't really fit.

Comment: @BoltClock But just because *you* think 1 of the 10 questions is good doesn't mean they can't think all 10 were bad.  You'd need to know that they downvoted a post *that they themselves felt was a good post* if you want to argue some form of abuse.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, that's why I mentioned conditioning - there's the possibility someone is so jaded by the 9 questions they felt were bad, that they downvote the 1 question they would have otherwise considered good, just because it was posted in that tag. So the overall question here is, is that abuse, in the same way that voting on a post based on who posted it regardless of its quality is abuse, or is that just someone exercising their right to their unpopular opinion?

Comment: "There are some tags that should immediately be down voted (for being off-topic),"  Should off-topic questions be downvoted, or should we simply vote to close them? IMHO a close vote is sufficient -- especially if it's a perfectly good question for a different site. I'd do both only for a question that's both bad *and* off-topic.

Comment: @KeithThompson Keep in mind that down votes are removed before migration.

Comment: I agree with everything here except your opening statement - "There are some tags that should immediately be down voted"; that is just plain *wrong* the vote should reflect the overall quality of the post, not just the use of a meta tag

Comment: @BradLarson This feels a lot like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269082/spam-voting-should-we-stop-it except for down votes in a tag, rather than up votes along the entire site.

Comment: If it's off-topic, it should not be voted down; it should be close-voted.

Answer (score 14):

tl;dr: this is a problem, but it's also a symptom. There's probably room for improvement in clarifying scope.

Brad Larson has the right idea here (as usual). Here's [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322363/why-do-i-get-a-down-vote-on-every-vhdl-question-i-ask#comment340865_322363), for ease of reference and scrolling reduction:

> Let's say that I have identified one person who is pretty heavily downvoting posts in this tag. They're not targeting any one person, so our normal standards of handling serial downvoting don't apply. When one person is targeting another in revenge, that's pretty easy to make a call on, but not here. If I confront them about this, they will state that they're free to vote based on how they judge the quality of the content. The question is: how do I distinguish between votes that someone leaves based on their own strict quality standard and them abusing the voting system?

I see three levels of specificity here, for lack of a better term.

In the most specific case, this question is about VHDL. I do remember from way back in college an eternal debate about whether VHDL (well, actually, Verilog, but that's not too important for this situation) was a "real" language or "merely," as the name says, a "description language," and therefore somehow a second-class citizen. I'm not an expert here, so I'll keep my opinion to myself; it's not my place to issue a decree one way or the other, anyways. Although I will say I suspect that this is like vi vs. emacs or tabs vs. spaces and there will always be some die-hards in each camp.

In the least specific case, this question is about the extrapolation of what Brad says. If someone is downvoting all posts that meet some personal criteria, but those criteria don't fit our traditional definition of targeted, malicious or otherwise inappropriate voting, is that okay or not? I think that's just a little too broad to answer; in other words, the circumstances make a difference.

That leaves us with the middle case. <s>To be fair, I should say that I haven't done any digging on what's actually happening in this actual situation yet. But based on what's been presented so far, I suspect that</s> I've just taken a look at recent voting patterns and it seems that [Laurel's idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322427/) of a "vigilante" (actually, I think that term is sort of loaded, I'm going to say "contrarians" instead) is correct <s>and even if it's not, it's a good discussion to have</s>. So: what do we do when people are targeting a particular tag/topic for downvotes?

We've already established that there's nothing inherently wrong with the posts. The natural target for blame would seem to be the voters. In at least some cases, though, I think the actual fault might come from ambiguity over whether the tag is appropriate or not. That ambiguity makes Brad's question about how to identify abuse unanswerable. If there's a real concern about whether a topic belongs on a site, the community needs to come to consensus about that (through meta discussion). If and when a topic is deemed valid, this sort of mass-downvoting should become off-limits (i.e. a flaggable offense).

That, finally, brings us back around to the topic of VHDL. Is it a legitimate Stack Overflow topic? (Note that I didn't say "programming language"; our only goal is to determine whether it meets our community's standards or not.) Based on the tag's performance so far, most of the community seems to think so—or at least be ambivalent—but it's probably worth coming up with a somewhat more canonical answer (in a fresh, separate meta post). <s>And also for someone like me to see if the initial "vigilante downvoter" assumption is valid after all.</s>

Comment: "Is it a legitimate Stack Overflow topic?" Since you can program with it (including GUI and stuff) without ever having to think about any hardware I'd really say *yes*, it is a legitimate SO topic. Such questions would be totally out of scope of the other sites, including EE.

Comment: There's no question that it's a real programming language. It's closely derived from Ada, it's consistent and clean, and the LRM in front of me has 264 pages. The only thing that sets it aside from 'normal' languages is that it's massively parallel, and deals with the flow of time. The same is essentially true of Verilog (although the language design is, to say the least, poor). The basic problem here is that there are very few users of these languages, and most of them are not 'programmers'.

Comment: I agree that these questions are interesting, but I'm pretty tempted to flag this post as "not-an-answer."

Comment: @Michael how so? OP asked "why am I/these questions being downvoted"; my answer is "because we've created an environment that allows (and to a degree, supports) such behavior, and we should do something about it."

Comment: I interpret the OP's questions as "who is doing this" and "what should I do about it?" to which your answers are "I haven't checked on Laurel's theory" and "let's talk about this and come up with a canonical community decision." I think your post is _great_ input for the community discussion, but it doesn't answer OP's questions.

Comment: @Michael Meta is different than the regular site. It's not as strict. Some questions on meta don't even have clear cut answers, only opinions (and should *not* be closed on that basis). "Answers" don't have the answer the question on meta. They just need to contain useful information. A "not-an-answer" flag would be *totally* inappropriate for this post.

Answer (score -33):

I hadn't noticed you being down-voted. The issue is likely to be that there are a very small number of people on the VHDL and Verilog tags, and one or two of them are very keen on Minimum/Complete/Verifiable, so their votes are disproportionally counted.

Having said that, SO doesn't work for VHDL and Verilog questions anyway. Most of the very small number of questions are:

1. homework (almost always BCD counters?!), or
2. make no sense at all, or
3. posted by someone who has no reputation and either won't read the answers or won't accept them.

And many of the answers are just plain wrong, but are just as likely to be accepted as a correct one.

comp.lang.vhdl is probably still the best place for VHDL, if it's still alive.

electronics.stackexchange.com is the wrong place for HDL questions, except incidentally - VHDL and Verilog are proper languages with proper LRMs (well, one of them, anyway), and questions should be programming questions, not electronics questions. VHDL is a systems simulation language, not "electronics".

**EDIT**
Ok, to address some of the comments below.

1. I'm pretty sure I know who does the down-voting, and I'm pretty sure he does it because he's fixated on MVE. I have no interest in MVE, but his actions, if it is him, are within the spirit of SO.
2. I have no objection to the OP's original VHDL question; that should have been obvious.
3. I spent 15-odd years on comp.lang.vhdl and comp.lang.verilog. It's a fact that they worked and were of very high quality. This hasn't happened on SO. It *has* happened for other languages, but not the HDLs. That's not a 'rant'; it's a rational analysis.
4. I almost never downvote questions; even homework questions. I was pointing out that SO doesn't work for these languages, and this is one of the issues. You should bear in mind that the OP and myself may be the only people in this discussion who have ever contributed to the VHDL tag.

Comment: Please note that down votes on answers here on meta means "I don't agree". I don't agree with your answer because I think the vote pattern for these tags _does_ look quite fishy. I think the OP has stumbled upon something that needs further investigation by a diamond mod.

Comment: Yes, many questions are homework questions, but this is not against the SO or EE rules (as far as I know). Neither is there a possibility to downvote silly questions or say that people should read a book on HDL first before posting question. Requesting a MVE is mostly required to reproduce the issue. Moreover, the used toolchain is also essential. I'm not sure why many people don't improved or edit there questions to answer our requestings, so we can help out. Many questions are also cross posts. He can't handle these questions, because cross-posts can not be marked as duplicates.

Comment: The first 3 lines somehow address the question, though I agree with Lundin that such a pattern is suspicious and should be investigated, and therefore I disagree with you. The rest is a rant, and the gist is "find another site because both questions and answers here are crap". Are you so surprised to get downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't see how your answer is relevant to the question. OP's questions are clearly not homework and make sense. "I hadn't noticed you being down-voted" - that's a strange thing to say too, because the fact is obvious to anyone with enough reputation to view upvotes/downvotes. Fabio is right.

Comment: > Please note that down votes on answers here on meta means "I don't agree". 

This practice sucks because it makes the answer unreadable for other people.

Comment: Your third point about the post being submitted by someone with no rep who won't accept any answers is completely irrelevant. Posts should stand on their own merit, regardless of who created it. If a high rep user creates a terrible post, it should be downvoted (and potentially deleted) just as much as a good post from a low rep user should be commended and upvoted. A little green tick next to a post is not necessarily an indicator of quality either.

Comment: I was a no upvote/downvote on your post till I read your first point in the "EDIT" section. There is no way you can be 100% sure. You can always take a guess, but it's wrong saying that there is only one user doing this. As per your guesses, I can even blame that you do the downvotes. Will someone believe me? No. This is the same thing with your answer.

Comment: "This hasn't happened on SO. It has happened for other languages, but not the HDLs." I would argue that the goal for the benefit of this community would be to make that work. While I don't dispute your analysis, how do you propose to make SO work for these tags/HDLs, aside from saying to go to an off-site resource "if it's still alive"? They are undisputably programming languages that are on-topic for SO. The fact that the tags are a so-called cesspool is possibly a self-fulfilling prophecy due to the stagnation and downvoting in the tag.

Comment: @paebbels EE does not respond kindly to homework questions. Good questions where they tried, failed, but showed their work may stay open, but most get dv and vtc because of lack of effort.

Comment: @paebbels this post mentioned EE multiple times, and I replied to your statement that homework is okay on EE.

Comment: Oh sorry, I have totally forgotten this one :). You're right.With homework questions I referred to SO homework questions.

Comment: @cde That still doesn't explain why downvotes are being sent to non-HW questions. Additionally, investigating what made comp.lang.vhdl work may be a good step moving forward, here or in a new meta post.

Answer (score -76):

That tag is, frankly, a cesspool of non-MVCE, no-effort, "do my homework" questions. Most of the downvotes appear to be deserved.

There is no rule against downvoting in a tag (see [Serial downvotes for single tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321332/serial-downvotes-for-single-tag)). If somebody ends up serial-downvoting a specific user, that will be reversed by the serial-voting system.

Comment: How does this answer help the OP? His VHDL questions are, as far as I've seen, of sufficient quality.

Comment: @Cerbrus It does highlight a problem though - similar to robo-reviewers, there are robo-downvoters too.

Comment: That doesn't help the OP, or answer his question.

Comment: The discussion seems to have moved beyond the OP's specific question.

Comment: And the discussion can be deleted at any time leaving this answer looking a bit confusing.

Comment: Surely downvoting good questions because they happen to be in a cesspool of non-MVCE homework questions isn't conducive to attempting to convert said cesspool to a good tag with good questions.