# What are the best practices for posting VHDL questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, debugging-questions

I see that there is detailed information available for posting questions about errors in software. I am not entirely sure about how I can apply this advice to hardware code.

How can I post a minimal and verifiable code for VHDL on SO?

P.S. **I am aware of the fact that SO is designed to serve software developers.** However, I have seen a lot of questions on VHDL as well which received satisfactory answers. Hence, I too wish to post my questions on hardware programming here.

Comment: There is also a VHDL tag on [Electronics.SE]. As always, check their [Help Center](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [tag info](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/vhdl/info) before posting there. I guess VHDL is one of those subjects that is applicable to multiple sites.

Comment: What aspect of "minimal and verifiable" is holding you back with regards to VHDL? Is it that "minimal" is hard to do? Is it that "verifiable" may depend on vendor context? Or is there something else that's a problem?

Comment: @Bart Lets suppose that I have created a complex design and am not getting the expected output. I could try simulating and writing test benches. But even after that, if I cannot pinpoint the cause of the error, how can I properly inform the readers on SO about my problem?

Comment: Well that is hardly specific to VHDL. This can also happen on 'traditional' coding issues.

Comment: @Patrice How can I pinpoint the cause of the problem and then post such a code that people can run on their systems and get the errors that I am getting? I find it to be a more daunting challenge in VHDL because I feel modules are interconnected and posting just one or two might not properly convey the message.

Comment: @a_sid replace "modules"with "classes"and you have the same issue on traditional coding.... Not saying it is easy. Just failing to see how it is different than traditional code.... Having done both, an MVCE is as hard in one as the other I find

Comment: Related: *[VHDL and other hardware level languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184808)* and *[Why do I get a down vote on every VHDL question I ask?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322363)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thank you for the links.

Comment: @Patrice Thank you for the advice.