# Is it against the rules to vote by tag?

Tags: support, voting

I know that voting by user is not OK. Upvoting all of a user's posts isn't OK, nor is downvoting. But what about voting by tag? What if I downvote questions for having a tag for a language I am not fond of, but is that against the rules?

Comment: Please don't downvote a question just because it has a language you don't like.

Answer (score 18):

No, it is not technically against the rules. That is, it is not vote fraud or user targeting.

But…

1. Why would you want to? If you don't find the tag/technology interesting, then just don't look at it. You can even add it to your "ignored" tags list, so that questions with that tag will either appear greyed out or be hidden altogether. Votes are meant to rank content based on its quality and thus serve as a signal to other users. That you don't like the technology is a false signal, so we'd *prefer* that you avoid this.
2. You only have a limited number of votes per day. Unless it's a *very* niche technology, you're not going to even be able to make a dent, so why waste your votes trying?

Related reading:

- [Serial downvotes for single tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321332/serial-downvotes-for-single-tag)
- [Why do I get a down vote on every VHDL question I ask?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322363/why-do-i-get-a-down-vote-on-every-vhdl-question-i-ask)
- [Why is almost every Go question downvoted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339273/why-is-almost-every-go-question-downvoted)
- [Is it dangerous to patrol a tag with issues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332564/is-it-dangerous-to-patrol-a-tag-with-issues)
- [Is there a downvote rate per tag statistic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337143/is-there-a-downvote-rate-per-tag-statistic)

Comment: I would think that, if a moderator flag was raised that someone noticed that all, say, [php] questions were downvoted over a period of a week, that someone would investigate that and the votes would be reversed. I would also hope the person responsible would have a note dropped in their inbox as well...

Comment: Probably not....

Comment: Well then, I've got a bone to pick with [localdatetime]... ;-)

Comment: Ahah, [tag:php] is given a purpose

Comment: To be fair, I do occasionally go through tags like [tag:kali-linux] that are 99% unsalvageable garbage looking for stuff that needs to be cleared out.